# setInterval javascript - how to call function

Tags: javascript, setinterval

Here is the simple example of two similar use of setInterval function:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MwYOOJ

In the first example setInterval function does not work, in the second version where below syntax was used it's working fine.

```
/* This part does not work */
var i = 0;
function displayNumber() {
  i++;
  $('#result').html(i);
}

setInterval(displayNumber(), 500);

/* This part does work */
var j = 0;
function displayNumberOk() {
  j++;
  $('#result-ok').html(j);
}

setInterval(function() { displayNumberOk() }, 500);
```

In specification I can find:

```
setInterval(function,milliseconds,param1,param2,...)
```

Why can't I use function name directly?

Comment: Why are you posting the working version of your code here and not the broken version? Don't make people visit links to discover what the problem is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the first example, where you have

```
setInterval(displayNumber(), 500);
```

you are **calling** `displayNumber` directly, instead of passing it as parameter.

In fact, using

```
setInterval(displayNumber, 500);
```

should be sufficient (notice the lack of `()`, so that it is not **called** but rather **passed** as parameter).